# ¿Cómo leer archivo linea por linea en javascript?

Tags: javascript

¿Hay manera de leer un **file** en javascript sin el uso de un input file y poderlo leer linea a linea?

La duda surge porque en este caso la ruta del archivo la extraigo de la base datos y quisiera leerlo linea por linea sin el uso de los input file

Comment: te refieres a un archivo alojado en el servidor?

Comment: Si, en este caso la ruta del archivo lo extraigo de la base datos y quisiera leerlo linea por linea sin el uso de los input file

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta y concretar mejor qué quieres hacer: ¿Cuál es el origen del archivo? ¿Hablamos de javascript en el navegador o NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

Para leer el archivo sin usar un input file puedes usar una función en jquery  $.get:

```
$.get( "archivo.txt", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Para mayor información sobre la función, puedes dar click [aquí](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: De esa manera se podria leer linea por linea?

Comment: tendrías que hacer un each a la variable data para recorrer el contenido